# objdump Vs sh4-linux-objdump

Tags: rhel

I need this command (sh4-linux-objcopy) in RHEL 6. I could not find the package by `yum install` , neither there is a corresponding rpm.

[Here is](http://www.stlinux.com/u-boot/mkimage/kernel-images) how I want to use it:

```
sh4-linux-objdump -h vmlinux | grep .empty_zero_page | awk '{print $4}'
```

But `objdump` is installed and works fine.

So is there any difference between `objdump` and  `sh4-linux-objdump` and what is `sh4-linux-`

Answer (score 1):

For cross compiling I'd take a look at this wiki article titled: [Cross-compiling Linux kernel on x86 64](http://linuxdriverproject.org/mediawiki/index.php/Cross-compiling_Linux_kernel_on_x86_64) from the Linux Driver project.

#### RPMs that contain 'objdump'

The packages that contain the various `sh*-linux-objdump` tools are contained in these RPMs.

```
$ yum search binutils|grep sh
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, changelog, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
binutils-sh-linux-gnu.x86_64 : Cross-build binary utilities for sh-linux-gnu
binutils-sh64-linux-gnu.x86_64 : Cross-build binary utilities for sh64-linux-gnu
```

*binutils-sh-linux-gnu*

```
$ repoquery -q -l binutils-sh-linux-gnu.x86_64 | grep objdump
/usr/bin/sh-linux-gnu-objdump
/usr/sh-linux-gnu/bin/objdump
/usr/share/man/man1/sh-linux-gnu-objdump.1.gz
```

*binutils-sh64-linux-gnu*

```
$ repoquery -q -l binutils-sh64-linux-gnu.x86_64 | grep objdump
/usr/bin/sh64-linux-gnu-objdump
/usr/sh64-linux/bin/objdump
/usr/share/man/man1/sh64-linux-gnu-objdump.1.gz
```

#### So are they equivalent?

I would say that `objdump` and `sh4-linux-objdump` are in fact equivalent with the caveat that there are specialized versions of `objdump` for different types of files.

You can see this if you search the YUM repositories looking for all the matches to `*objdump$`.

```
$ repoquery -q -f -l  */*objdump | grep "objdump$" | head -10
/usr/arm-none-eabi/bin/objdump
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump
/usr/bin/c6x-linux-gnu-objdump
/usr/c6x-uclinux/bin/objdump
/usr/bin/sh-linux-gnu-objdump
/usr/sh-linux-gnu/bin/objdump
/usr/bin/sh64-linux-gnu-objdump
/usr/sh64-linux/bin/objdump
/usr/bin/hppa64-linux-gnu-objdump
/usr/hppa64-linux-gnu/bin/objdump
```

And the packages that provide a file that matches the pattern:

```
$ repoquery -q -f */*objdump | head -10
arm-none-eabi-binutils-cs-0:2013.11.24-1.fc19.x86_64
binutils-c6x-linux-gnu-0:2.23.51.0.3-1.fc19.x86_64
binutils-sh-linux-gnu-0:2.23.88.0.1-2.fc19.x86_64
binutils-sh64-linux-gnu-0:2.23.88.0.1-2.fc19.x86_64
binutils-hppa64-linux-gnu-0:2.23.88.0.1-2.fc19.x86_64
binutils-powerpc64-linux-gnu-0:2.23.88.0.1-2.fc19.x86_64
binutils-x86_64-linux-gnu-0:2.23.88.0.1-2.fc19.x86_64
binutils-arm-linux-gnu-0:2.23.51.0.3-1.fc19.x86_64
binutils-openrisc-linux-gnu-0:2.23.51.0.3-1.fc19.x86_64
llvm-0:3.3-4.fc19.i686
```

**NOTE:** The output above in both examples is limited via the command `head -10` just to show partial lists here.